# Is Galen Marek ("Starkiller") part of the Star Wars canon?

Tags: star-wars, video-games, canon

Is [Galen Marek](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Galen_Marek) considered part of the Star Wars canon? More specifically, **does he appear in any canon property?**

Comment: Starkiller... such a name. Well at least no one can ever accuse the Sith of being too subtle.

Comment: Sorry, but John Sheridan is Starkiller.

Comment: I don't think it's a dupe. This question is about a specific individual and whether or not they're mentioned in any canon property

Comment: @Edlothiad His first appearance was in the Soul Caliber game because that game was released before his appearance in *The Force Unleashed*. But the way you wrote it implied that the character was invented out of the Star Wars universe and imported into it. That's not really the case. I think it makes more sense to just link to his Wookieepedia page.

Comment: @Gallifreyan, I stand corrected, I wasn't aware that all the other questions of the same format, i.e. "Was X part of the star wars canon" were made duplicates of that question.

Comment: @Gallifreyan, fine I did it for the reopen votes (jokes). Although I do hope Jason Baker got his reopen vote :P

Comment: Recently, either Filoni or Hidalgo mentioned that Starkiller was brought up as a potential Inquisitor to appear in Rebels. It didn't end up happening, but I feel like it's relevant here.

Comment: Found the [source](https://clips.twitch.tv/MuddyDependableCoyoteThisIsSparta). It was actually Sam Witwer.

Answer (score 13):

Take a look at the Wookieepedia [article on Canon](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Canon); the [2014 Reboot](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Canon#2014_reboot) section talks about the changes due to Disney.

To quote:

> On April 25, 2014, a StarWars.com press release confirmed that the films of the sequel trilogy would not adhere to the post–Return of the Jedi Expanded Universe,[9] with further comments from LucasBooks Senior Editor Jennifer Heddle confirming that the EU as a whole is no longer considered canon. The EU has been re-termed "Legends," with related publications remaining in print under that banner.
>
> Since then, the only previously published material still considered canon are the six original trilogy/prequel trilogy films and the *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* television series and film. Most material published after April 25—such as the *Star Wars: Rebels* TV series and all novels beginning with *A New Dawn*—is also considered part of the new canon, on account of the creation of the Lucasfilm Story Group, which currently oversees continuity as a whole. Characters under the Legends banner are still available for use as needed, even if events concerning them are no longer canon.

Given that Starkiller's appearances are restricted to the video games, EU Novels and comics, his presence is officially part of the **Legends** banner and as such, not canon.

Comment: And the Ewok films? You forget the Ewok films!

Comment: @k-h-w - unfortunately the recent changes to the Star Wars canon levels have rendered this answer largely incorrect.

Comment: @Richard -- Yep; but we can only answer these when they are asked, and AT THE TIME, it was correct.  Might be worth a followup question, tho - 'Now, with the Disney acquisition of the Star Wars franchise, how is Canon determined' or something :)

Comment: @k-h-w - Surely the appropriate thing to do would be to delete your (wrong) answer, then write a new (right) one.

Comment: @No, I don't think so at all.  It was a correct answer when it was asked, and it's been amended with updated information.  If the information had simply proven to be wrong, I'd agree with you, but it wasn't -- the correct answer changed.  Also, since mine was never accepted as a correct answer, it's just a now-outdated answer that previously WAS correct.  I'm inclined to leave it, the same way we close but don't delete many answers.  That being said, I don't know if there is a SE policy on what to do when valid answers change due to canon changes; might be a worthwhile question on Meta.

Comment: @Richard -- I'd ask it, but 'Ask a Question' on Meta is giving me "The page isn't redirecting properly" and failing.

Comment: Either editing or adding a new answer are the usual solutions to this sort of thing.  It's worth noting that the edit here is actually incorrect, (most of) T-canon and above are what makes up the new canon, as it includes *The Clone Wars*.

Comment: @keen -- Thanks; I've rolled it back to the earlier form while I look for better information to update it.  I'd suggest that someone more familiar with the current details (you, perhaps) might want to add an answer, and I'll tag mine as outdated.

Comment: @K-H-W - A good edit. I've also taken the liberty of extending your answer to refer to Starkiller.

Comment: By the older answer definitions, wouldn't be fair to say that all material prior to april 25th is now part of the S (secondary canon). Then, the original answer would still hold, at least partially.